# Running sh script: «Permission denied» despite the executable bit and root rights

Tags: bash, shell, virtualbox, executable

I installed Debian in [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) (for various experiments which usually broke my system) and tried to launch the VirtualBox guest addon script. I logged in as root and tried to launch `autorun.sh`, but I got «Permission denied». `ls -l` shows that the script have an executable rights.

Sorry, that I can't copy the output -- VirtualBox absolutely have no use without the addon, as neither a shared directory, nor a shared clipboard works. But just for you to be sure, I copied the rights by hands:

```
#ls -l ./autorun.sh
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 6966 Mar 26 13:56 ./autorun.sh
```

At first I thought that it may be that the script executes something that gave the error. I tried to replace `/bin/sh` with something like `#/pathtorealsh/sh -xv`, but I got no output — it seems the script can't even be executed.

I have not even an idea what could cause it.

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Try running it with bash explicitly: `bash -x ./autorun.sh".  Maybe this will give an additional clue.

Comment: What is output of `mount | grep noexec`?

Comment: @Gnouc, you're right, the mounted «cdrom» have the `noexec` set. Probably you may post it as an answer; meanwhile I am trying to remount it with an exec rights. Hm, I didn't even knew that the filesystem could have such an attribute.

Comment: And if you try to run it via going `sh ./autorun.sh` what happens?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Maybe your file system is mounted with `noexec` option set, so you can not run any executable files. From [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) documentation:

> noexec
>
> Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted
>   filesystem. (Until recently it was possible to run binaries anyway
>   using a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary. This trick fails since
>   Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)

Try:

```
mount | grep noexec
```

Then check if your file system is listed in output.

If yes, you can solve this problem, by re-mounting file system with `exec` option:

```
mount -o remount,exec filesystem
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I had to unmount and then remount normally. Then it worked fine.

Comment: @datakid: What is your fs?

Comment: I am having this issue with debian 9, some files are permission denied if the scripts is running as root, but it identify as root... like a windows behavior, if i remove & the script worked! =[

Comment: I was getting a very strange message, which turned out to be because of `noexec`: "sh: 75: script.sh: Permission denied"

Comment: Also, if it complains about not being able to remount /dev/whatever because it's write protected, you will need to make sure your remount command tells it to mount RO (e.g. `mount -o remount,exec,ro`)

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm. I added "exec" to disk mount entry in /etc/fstab on my raspberry pi.

Comment: Why in the world was my partition mounted with such option? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4):

`bash -x ./filename.filetype` should work. It worked for me when I got permission denied as a root user.

Comment: No, as in the end the problem turned out to be the `noexec` mount option, this won't work, because there could be more files that have to be executed; i.e. the `filename.filetype` would gasp trying to execute other files from the same filesystem. You can easily check it with a simplified test: create a two line script which prints "hello", then just calls himself again, but do not set executable rights. If you execute it with `-x`, it would print "hello", but then the recursive call line would trigger an error.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when I edited a bash file in my Google Collab workspace and tried to run it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is to use **source**.  I was on a storage volume of very important data. This volume is mounted as noexec.  I have a simple shell script that is executable but got permission problem.

```
./fixsamplesheet.sh # this guy is executable
-bash: ./fixsamplesheet.sh: Permission denied

source fixsamplesheet.sh # worked fine
```

Only tested on my Ubuntu.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, you are still not able to run it as an executable. You are running `bash` as an executable which reads the information from the `.sh` file.

Comment: The mechanism is to execute the commands in the current shell, not using the *.sh as if it is executable.  Agree, not the true solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem installing Guest Additions on my copy of Debian Buster in Virtual Box.

As a work-around I simply copied the file `VBoxLinuxEditions.run` to the home directory of Debian and ran it from there using sudo. This not the solution as to why the script could not be run, but at least I was able to install Guest Additions.

Interestingly, I had no problem installing Guest Additions on my version of MX Linux which I have installed in Virtual Box, despite the fact that MX Linux is based on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the extensions ISO file as a "virtual" CD.

In the guest I run, I `cd` to the appropriate mount point, such as
`cd '/media/some_username/VBox_GAs_6.1.18'` (name is dependent on version number)

Then run `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Restart the VM to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that worked for me in a Debian 12 VM was to copy the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file from the CD to my home folder, change permissions to add execution, then run it as root.

BUT, I forgot that guest additions compiles itself so if the prerequisites are not installed it will complain and halt.

So do this **first** before trying to run the guest additions:

```bash
sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Once that's done, run the guest additions run file in your home folder. After that's completed you'll want to reboot.

After reboot, confirm the guest additions are working. The quick test I use is to resize the VM window and see if the desktop resizes too. If it does they are working.

Don't forget to delete the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file from your home folder.